# For locale-sensitive functions, is it more common to pass the std::locale or the needed facet object(s)?

Tags: c++, stl, locale, coding-style

Recently I wrote a family of functions for trimming leading and trailing whitespace off of an input string. As the concept of "whitespace" is locale-dependent, I realized that I would need to either pass in a `const std::ctype<char_t>` reference or a `const std::locale` reference and call `std::use_facet<std::ctype<char_t> >` on the `const std::locale` object.

In my library, I decided upon passing a `const std::locale` reference because I figured that the `std::locale` object encapsulated the entirety of locale information, and that `std::use_facet` was the library-specific mechanism of access. However, I then started wondering whether it might be a better choice (perhaps it is more common?) to pass in the `const std::ctype<char_t>` reference for direct use by the functions.

Which is more common in locale-sensitive libraries:  passing the `const std::locale` reference or const-references to the needed facets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing how the standard library's `isspace()` is actually `std::isspace(charT, const std::locale&)`, I would think it would follow the principle of the least surprise if your trim whitespace functions also took `const locale&`.

But what's stopping you from allowing both?